# Splitting text and numbers in dataframe in python

Tags: python, split

I have a dataframe df with column name 'col' as the second column and the data looks like:
[Dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jk17U.png)

Want to separate text part in one column with name "Casing Size" and numerical part with "DepthTo" in other column.
[Desired Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SMq3d.png)

```
import pandas as pd
import io
from google.colab import files
uploaded = files.upload()
df = pd.read_excel(io.BytesIO(uploaded['Test-Checking.xlsx']))

#Method 1
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=df, columns=['col'])
df2 = df2.col.str.extract('([a-zA-Z]+)([^a-zA-Z]+)', expand=True)
df2.columns = ['CasingSize', 'DepthTo']
df2

#Method 2
def split_col(x):
  try:
      numb = float(x.split()[0])
      txt = x.split()[1]
  except:
       numb = float(x.split()[1])
       txt = x.split()[0]
    x['col1'] = txt
    x['col2'] = numb
 df2['col1'] = df.col.apply(split_col)
 df2
```

Tried two methods but none of them work correctly. Is there anyone help me?

Code in [Google Colab](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/15dugz-11gLzFqp0qRAz__KS6IwWHjsTG?usp=sharing)

Excel File [Attached](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ihQ9Rh2HoDrzlqArrKuinQJNXv_ilhn1/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0):

## Try this

first you need to return the  the values from your functions. then you can unpack them into your columns using the to_list()

```
def sample(x):
    b,y=x.split()
    return b,y

temp_df=df2['col'].apply(sample)

df2[['col1','col2']]=pd.DataFrame(temp_df.tolist())
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try splitting the values into a list, then sorting them so that the numerical part comes first.  Then you could apply `pd.Series` and assign back to the two columns.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'col':["PWT 69.2", '283.5 HWT', '62.9 PWT', '284 HWT']})

df[['Casing Size','DepthTO']] = df['col'].str.split().apply(lambda x: sorted(x)).apply(pd.Series)

print(df)
```

Output

```
         col Casing Size DepthTO
0   PWT 69.2        69.2     PWT
1  283.5 HWT       283.5     HWT
2   62.9 PWT        62.9     PWT
3    284 HWT         284     HWT
```